# using awk to match a PATH starting with /root/ and ending before character "

Tags: awk

i have a command that produces a random output with a path in it
And i need to extract this path using awk.
The path always starts with the same pattern (lets assume it always starts with /root) but the rest can change

for example :

```
error reason  05/30/2017 12:18:37 [74575:45687]: "/root/this/is/my/path/" random text random text random text random text random text random    text
```

to extract /root/this/is/my/path/ : I have tryed using grep + awk in the following way :

```
command.sh | grep error  |awk '/root/{mypath=$6}'.
```

But i then figured out my path was not always located at the same place. more over, i don't want to extract the double quotes.

```
i need to have /root/this/is/my/path/ not "/root/this/is/my/path/"
```

Anyone can help please?

Comment: try `grep -oP '\d{5}:\d{5}]: "\K[^"]+'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method you may adopt:

```
command.sh | awk -F\" '/^error/{ print $2}'
```

Output:

```
/root/this/is/my/path/
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your differents answers, i like the thrid answer because it's very simple.
 the first two seem interesting but very complicated for me now .i ll study them  anyways and try to understand what they do.

Comment: Thanks for it. And please kindly check to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
command.sh | awk '/^error/{ for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ( $i ~ /^"/){ gsub(/"/, "", $i); print $i} }' -
```

Output:

```
/root/this/is/my/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
command.sh | awk '/^error/{ match($0,/\/root[^"]+/); print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }'
```

The output:

```
/root/this/is/my/path/
```